# Include GLES to CMakeLists in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In Android NDK old version, we include GLES like this:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lGLESv1_CM
```

But in newest version, Android uses CMakeLists instead of Android.mk with the same purpose. So how to add GLES/GLES2/GLES3 dependency to CMakeList file? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The difference between the gradle scripting ndk module and cmakelist external tool is the way to define your script. In this case,
 you need to create your CMake script (CMakeLists.txt, and change your gradle file to activate the external tool):

CMakelists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# now build app's shared lib
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")

add_library(gljni SHARED
            your_code.cpp)

# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(gljni
                      android
                      log 
                      EGL
                      GLESv2) #here you can put your opengl linking library.
```

The command target_link_libraries specifies the libraries that they are going to be linked.

In the gradle file you need to specify the external native build, adding cmake options such as compiler, android native version etc.

```
 externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                // Available argumetns are inside ${SDK}/cmake/.../android.toolchain.cmake file
                arguments '-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-9',
                          '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Unai.

Comment: I tried but it still stuck the last problem, it said undefined reference to GL functions, see this photo https://flic.kr/p/RWxvCK

Comment: try to add "android" keyword to the target link libraries.

Comment: it is weird because, opengl is inside of NDK, so you do not need to specify where the libraries are located. The functions that you are using what opengl versions uses?

Comment: Maybe try adding `find_library(GLES2-lib GLESv2)` after CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, and then for your project `target_link_libraries(${Project} ${GLES2-lib})`.